# Find Subset of collection which has duplicate - Leetcode

Tags: java, subset, backtracking

I am trying to solve [subset-II](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/description/)  leetcode problem.

problem statement is : Given a collection of integers that might contain duplicates, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set). The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
private boolean isAlreadyExplored(int [] nums , int currElem , int currElemIndex) {

    for(int i=0;i<currElemIndex;i++) {
        if(currElem==nums[i]) {
            System.out.println("Already exposed : " +currElem + " i : " + i);
            return true;
        }
    }       
    return false;
}

private void subsetsWithDupHelper(int[] nums,List<List<Integer>> choosenList , List<Integer> choosen , int start) {

    choosenList.add(new  ArrayList<Integer>(choosen));

    for(int i=start;i<nums.length; i++) {

        //Explore only when the current elem's duplicate is not explored already. 

        if(i>start&&isAlreadyExplored(nums,nums[i],i)) {   // i> start - this will skip the check for first elem.
            continue;
        }       
        choosen.add(nums[i]);

        subsetsWithDupHelper(nums, choosenList, choosen, i+1); // increasing the start bcoz we are not repitating.

        choosen.remove(choosen.size()-1); //backtrack.
    }
}


public List<List<Integer>> subsetsWithDup(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> choosenList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> choosen = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Arrays.sort(nums);    // If i uncomment this line it is working. 
    subsetsWithDupHelper(nums, choosenList, choosen, 0);        
    return choosenList; 
}
```

I wrote the code without the `Arrays.sort(nums);` then in discussion forum I could see some are suggesting to sort the input. when I tried to sort the input, my code works.

But I don't understand why sorting is required?

Can someone help me in understanding what I am missing? what is the significance of sorting here?

Comment: First, I am clarifying that by power set you mean the sub"sets" that may also contain duplicates (up to the amount that appear in the original set) but having no regard for order?

Next to explain why sorting is required:
Unless you sort, you may (if the same number is repeated with some number in between) have the same subset twice (for example, given nums = {2,1,2} you will have, among other subsets, {1,2} and {2,1}).
Sorting prevents this by ensuring that starting "later" won't yield previously seen results.

Comment: Unless you sort, you may (if the same number is repeated with some number in between) have the same subset twice  ---  I thought this will be taken care by the isAlreadyExplored() function. Since we are skipping the element if it is already added ... what is that i am missing?

Comment: Note that "isAlreadyExplored" is only called after adding the first element.
What could help is "walking through" the code with a simple example (such as the one I gave) and then realizing that unless sorted, these duplicates will appear.